# Analyzing load on Windows machine with respect to Linux /proc/loadavg calculation

Tags: linux, windows, performance, load

I have a program that runs on both Linux and Windows and reports the load on the machine. Since this program was originally written for Linux I want to implement Linux's load calculation alogorithm on Windows.

according to the proc man page:

```
/proc/loadavg
              The first three fields in this file are load average figures giving the number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk I/O (state D) averaged over 1, 5, and 15 minutes.  They  are  the
              same  as  the  load average numbers given by uptime(1) and other programs.  The fourth field consists of two numbers separated by a slash (/).  The first of these is the number of currently executing
              kernel scheduling entities (processes, threads); this will be less than or equal to the number of CPUs.  The value after the slash is the number of kernel scheduling entities that currently exist  on
              the system.  The fifth field is the PID of the process that was most recently created on the system.
```

I am interested in the first three indicators: load in the last 1,5 and 15 minutes.

I can't say I understand the calculation completely - does it take into account the number of processors on the machine? I guess it does but it isn't covered in the manual.

After all, how would you suggest to implement this on Windows?

Thanks in adavance.